# joins on tables without relation in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the work around of not being able to use `joins` on tables that don't have relation?

E.g:

```
class Student
end

class Lesson
end
```

There is no explicit correlation between Student and Lesson, however, in DB, we have implicit correlation: students.lesson_id and lessons.id.

Using pure SQL can join these two tables, however, using `joins` provided by rails like this:

```
Student.joins(:lesson).where('student.lesson_id=lesson.id')
```

will throw "Association named 'lesson' was not found on Student; perhaps you misspelled it?"

I'm looking for work around with below requirements:

- In order to improve the efficiency, using RDBMS queries will be ideal. (Rails sort_by, find etc are not)
- In order to improve readability, raw SQL is not ideal.

Is there any work around out there? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:lesson` in `joins(:lesson)` must be the name of a relation defined in `Student` model:

```rb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lesson
end
```

Then you can rewrite your query as:

```rb
Student.joins(:lesson).all
```

BUT this drives to N+1 queries in case you need to access `Lesson`:

```rb
students = Student.joins(:lesson).all
lesson_name = students.first.lesson.name
```

To avoid that use `includes` instead:

```rb
Student.includes(:lesson).all
```

You can (should) add the counter-part relation to `Lesson`:

```rb
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :students
end
```

BTW, you can use strings in a join:

```rb
Student.joins('join lessons on students.lesson_id = lessons.id')
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not able to add relation to these two models. But the last statement in your reply works.

Comment: @laahaa What to you mean you're not able to add relation, can't you update the model files in your project?

Comment: I am working on a project, which has bunch of unnecessary constraints, and one of it is to avoid adding extra association.

Answer (score -1):

The active record method `.joins` already joins on the foreign key. There is no need to specifiy it again in a where statement. You can use `where` to filter the results your receiving.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But my question bases on the fact that there is no relation between two models. @CAmador gave a worked answer.